# Hibernate OneToMany MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have two java hibernate entities:

```
@Entity
public class Match_soccer extends Match{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int mid;

    ...
```

And other one:

```
@Entity
public class Algo {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @OneToMany
    private List<Match_soccer> matches = new ArrayList<Match_soccer>();

    ...
```

And if I try save two different `Algo` entities but with some `matches` list I get `Duplicate entry '6028' for key 'UK_auyvi1qkpdtaqrpuyv9je5rda'` exception.

Hibernate create in database 3 tables: `Algo` `Match_soccer` and Table:

```
Algo_Match_soccer
with columns:
Algo1_id    int(11)
matches_mid int(11) PK
```

My goal is to assign list of matches to Algo. Matches can be some in 2 different Algo objects.

```
Algo a1 = new Algo();
Algo a2 = new Algo();
SoccerDAO sd = new SoccerDAO();
List<Match_soccer> ms = sd.getMatches(DateFrom,DateTo); // Matches from database
a1.setMatches(ms);
a2.setMatches(ms);
```

I use this function to insert:

```
public void insertAlgo(Algo1 a){

    try {           
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(a);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }
    catch (RuntimeException e) {
        session.getTransaction().rollback();
        session.clear();
        throw e;
}
```

Comment: 1. Could you please provide the code through which you're persisting the objects?

Comment: Persisting is where I insert Objects into database, yes? If yes I added in above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Matches can be some in 2 different Algo objects

Then you don't have a OneToMany association, but a ManyToMany association. since an Algo has several matches, and a match belongs to several algos.

Change your mapping, and change the database schema accordingly: the PK of the join table should be the pair of IDs, and not just the match ID.

Comment: Thanks, I changed to ManyToMany association, and now work as I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Due to `Match_soccer` could have relationships with many `Algo` entities instance, the `matches` association/collection must be`@**Many**ToMany.

If you leave the association as @OneToMany it will define the UK//PK constraint for `match_id` that doesn't allows you to set same matches to two different `Algo` instances